# How can I connect qml objects, signals with mechanics and slots in c++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to write mechanics in c++ and objects, signals from qml, how can I connect my main.qml with main.cpp ?

The best option will be (if it is possible) declaration, adding something like directory which make qml and c++ as one database without everytime slot and signal reference between two files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#connecting-to-qml-signals), here's one way to connect `QML` objects to `C++`:

```
// MyItem.qml

import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: item
    width: 100; height: 100

    signal qmlSignal(string msg)

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: item.qmlSignal("Hello from QML")
    }
}


class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void cppSlot(const QString &msg) {
        qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with message:" << msg;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view(QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));
    QObject *item = view.rootObject();

    MyClass myClass;
    QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),
                     &myClass, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));

    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: yes I saw this but I made post here because I don't uderstand this, when I must to add this , where and do I have to add this few lines for every signal and slot